# Function using SDL2 returning wrong enum value

Tags: c++, enums, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 with C++.

I've made a `Player` class. It contains an object from the `Input` class.

I've made two `Player` objects.

In the `Player` constructor `Player()`, I call `setControls()` on member `Input` object `m_Controls`. Then I call `keyPressed()` on the same object. Both those functions belong to class `Input`.

My "error" is on line 89, where I call `m_Controls.keyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_W)`.

The function loops thru `Input` member array `m_Keys` -- keys the player can press. If the element it's iterating matches the `SDL_Scancode` passed to `keyPressed()`, it's supposed to return the corresponding value from the `Controls` enum.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

enum Controls {
    CONTROLS_INVALID=   -1,
    CONTROLS_QUIT_GAME,
    CONTROLS_UP,
    CONTROLS_RIGHT,
    CONTROLS_DOWN,
    CONTROLS_LEFT,
    CONTROLS_CONFIRM
};


class Input {
private:
    enum            {m_NumberOfKeys=    6};
    SDL_Scancode    m_Keys[m_NumberOfKeys];
    Controls        m_PressedKey;
public:
    Input(){}
    ~Input(){}

    void setControls(SDL_Scancode up, SDL_Scancode right, SDL_Scancode down, SDL_Scancode left, SDL_Scancode confirm){
        m_Keys[0]=  SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE;
        m_Keys[1]=  up;
        m_Keys[2]=  right;
        m_Keys[3]=  down;
        m_Keys[4]=  left;
        m_Keys[5]=  confirm;
    }

    Controls keyPressed(SDL_Scancode userInput){
        std::cout << "userInput: " << userInput << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_NumberOfKeys; ++i){
            std::cout << i << ' ' << m_Keys[i] << std::endl;
            if (m_Keys[i] == userInput){
                switch (i) {
                    case CONTROLS_QUIT_GAME:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_QUIT_GAME;
                        break;
                    case CONTROLS_UP:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_UP;
                        break;
                    case CONTROLS_RIGHT:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_RIGHT;
                        break;
                    case CONTROLS_DOWN:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_DOWN;
                        break;
                    case CONTROLS_LEFT:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_LEFT;
                        break;
                    case CONTROLS_CONFIRM:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_CONFIRM;
                        break;
                    default:
                        m_PressedKey=   CONTROLS_INVALID;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "m_PressedKey: " << m_PressedKey << std::endl;
        return m_PressedKey;
    }
};


class Player {
private:
    static int  s_IdGenerator;
    int         m_Id;
    Input       m_Controls;
public:
    Player() {
        m_Id=   s_IdGenerator++;
        std::cout << "Making player " << m_Id << std::endl;
        switch (m_Id) {
            case 1:
                m_Controls.setControls(SDL_SCANCODE_W, SDL_SCANCODE_D, SDL_SCANCODE_S, SDL_SCANCODE_A, SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE);
                break;
            case 2:
                m_Controls.setControls(SDL_SCANCODE_UP, SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT, SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN, SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT, SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        m_Controls.keyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_W);
        std::cout << "==\n";
    }
    ~Player(){}



    Input&  getControls(){
        return m_Controls;
    }
};

int Player::s_IdGenerator=  1;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);


    Player player1;
    Player player2;


    return 0;
}
```

Given the code above, `keyPressed()` returns the following after I make `player``:

```
Making player 1
userInput: 26
0 41
1 26
2 7
3 22
4 4
5 44
m_PressedKey: 1
```

So far it's good. `SDL_SCANCODE_W` is one of `player1`'s controls, so `m_PressedKey` is correctly set at `1`. But here's the output when `player2` is created:

```
Making player 2
userInput: 26
0 41
1 82
2 79
3 81
4 80
5 44
m_PressedKey: 0
```

Since `SDL_SCANCODE_W` is NOT part of `player2`'s controls, I want `m_PressedKey` to be set to `-1`. It's set to `0` instead.

What must I change to make this code set `m_PressedKey` to `-1` when `keyPressed()` gets an invalid `SDL_Scancode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the ctor or the keyPressed method initialize it; m_PressedKey = CONTROLS_INVALID; default ctors are evil:)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand exactly how you mean. I'm new to C++. Can you show me your example as code?

Comment: public:
    Input(){m_PressedKey = CONTROLS_INVALID; }
    ~Input(){}

Comment: or in the method:   Controls keyPressed(SDL_Scancode userInput){ 
        m_PressedKey = CONTROLS_INVALID;std::cout << "userInput: " << userInput << std::endl;